# Scheduling in Org mode without using mouse or track pad

Tags: org-mode, mouse

I'm scheduling items according to instructions here: https://orgmode.org/manual/Inserting-deadline_002fschedule.html#Inserting-deadline_002fschedule

I have pain in my hands that is exacerbated especially by using pointing devices such as a mouse or track pad. I can still tolerate typing pretty well. So far, Org-mode is the least mouse intensive organization tool I've found.

It looks like scheduling will require some mouse or track pad use. (ouch!) It looks like there isn't any way to specify a date in the future (after entering C-c C-s) other than with a pointing device or touch screen. I could make the touch screen work, but I'd prefer to keep my hands on the key board.

Comment: `C-c C-s` should bring up the calendar, which you navigate with `C-<arrow>`. Does this not work for you? I have never used a mouse with Emacs, and I depend on org-mode!

Comment: sorry, meant `Shift-<arrow>`

Comment: Just start typing after `C-c C-s`: `org` is pretty good at parsing text into dates.

Comment: Never thought of using Shift-<arrow>. thanks.

Comment: Fran and Tyler. Thanks. I like them both.

Answer (score 1):

Three ways to do this.

1. `C-c C-s <RET>` inserts the present date. Edit the date in the file buffer. `C-c C-s <RET>` will then change the day of the week to match the new date. Cumbersome, but what I figured out on my own after asking the question.
2. As Tyler suggested, use `Shift-<arrows>` to navigate around in the calendar Org-mode displays. Use `<RET>` to select the marked date.
3. `C-c C-s`, type the desired date in the echo area, `<RET>`. Thanks Fran.

Comment: Org is actually quite alright at accepting typed dates, if you figure out the format—it's not exactly natural-language. Just a number specifies the date, however if it's lower than the current day Org doesn't always interpret it as the future, despite what the manual says (in my experience). So, the format ‘1-15’ is the month and the day, i.e. January 15. A full date is ‘2020-11-15‘ for November 15. Then you add the time afterwards with a space, e.g. ‘16 10’ for 10 AM on the 16th, or ‘16 10:30’, or (I think) ‘16 10pm’.